# Flutter animate children in list view dynamically

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I am trying to implement a design that looks like this:

[image: example]

In the example the *currentItem* in the middle is of size `19` and its `opacity` is at 100%. The 2nd item below/above it is of size `13` with an `opacity` of 50% and the third items are of size `9` and with an`opacity` of 25%.

How could I implement something like this with Flutter? I've tried multiple things, for example `ListWheelScrollView` but I couldn't get the desired design.

One more requirement: The currentItem should be `tappable`.

Any idea how I could get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be to use a `CupertinoPicker` to achieve the design you're looking for.

For example, using a `StatefulWidget` to update and retrieve the `currentIndex` :

```
  static const double _containerHeight = 500;
  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: _containerHeight,
      child: CupertinoPicker.builder(
        itemExtent: _containerHeight / 3,
        diameterRatio: 20,
        useMagnifier: false,
        selectionOverlay: null,
        onSelectedItemChanged: (value) => setState(() => currentIndex = value),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: getFontSizeFromIndex(index)),
                child: Text(
                  'Das ist ein Text',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color:
                          Colors.white.withOpacity(getOpacityFromIndex(index))),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  double getFontSizeFromIndex(int index) => index == currentIndex
      ? 19
      : index == currentIndex - 1 || index == currentIndex + 1
          ? 13
          : 9;

  double getOpacityFromIndex(int index) => index == currentIndex
      ? 1
      : index == currentIndex - 1 || index == currentIndex + 1
          ? .5
          : .25;
```

To go further, you should considerate :

- `debouncing` the `onSelectedItemChanged` in order to prevent abusive rebuilds ;
- using a custom `ScrollController` and do some linear interpolations in order to make the animation smoother.

Here is the result :

[image]

Comment: never thought about `CuperthinoPicker`! Looking promising. My biggest concern with this solution is that the center item gets cut off when animating it away from the center. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: also, I know I mentioned specific values the fontSize and opacity should be changed to. But in a perfect animation, I would like both values changing dynamically depending on each scroll position pixel.

Comment: You can change the diameterRatio to 1.0 to remove this "cuts off" effect. You can also play with the offAxisFraction and the itemExtent to get the desired effect. For perfect animation, I advise you to use a CustomScrollController.